# Image management on Django

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, imagekit, django-imagekit, photologue

I'm trying to figure out which image management library to use on django. What is the difference between photologue, image-kit, and pil(python imaging library)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Photologue is a Django application to manage photos. It uses PIL for the image processing.

ImageKit is a Django Application for image processing. It is meant for adding images to existing models.

PIL is the underlying library for both of these (and actually, most if not all image processing scripts in Python).